# Slow performance on good hardware? 12.04

Tags: 14.04, performance

I am experiencing slow performance on good hardware, here are my specs:

```
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Memory: 8 GiG (7.7 Usable)
Processor: IntelCore i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz x 4
Graphics: Intel Ivybridge Mobile
OS Type: 64-bit
```

I run Google Chrome and I know it has the bad reputation of being a resource hog, but I have a ton of memory available. I have set my swappiness to 10.

Any and all help is always appreciated!

EDIT:
I have received the following error message:

Sorry, Ubuntu 14.04 has experienced an internal error.
If you notice further problems, try restarting the computer.

ExecutablePath
 /usr/bin/friends-dispatcher

Comment: Do you know what is slow?  The disk? The processor?  The Internet?  The mouse??  :P  The keyboard???  ;-) Did you try to run any performance utilities like `top` or `gnome-system-monitor`?

Answer (score 0):

This recipe often helps for me:

- press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Escape</kbd> (opens the task manager)
- see if the "GPU process" pops up high on the list
- if so get the gpu process id
- open a terminal window
- execute `kill -9 gpu_process_id`

This seems to always remove the sluggishness and jank I get after keeping my desktop chrome open for weeks with hundreds of tabs, without having to restart.

Apparently the opengcl library has resource handle leaks which cause this problem, according to a friend. When you kill the GPU process you recover those resources, but without having to restart chrome.